# How to remove old Schlage deadbolt lock

Tags: deadbolt

I need to remove this old Schalge lock which has a plate going around the door from front to back. The lock is not working anymore. I have attached some pictures.  Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIaOY.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have removed the cylinder screws, good. The cylinders should simply fall apart. That they are not means some corrosion or sticky stuff is inside the lock.

Try reinserting the screws partway, so they engage the threads but don't tighten down completely. Hammer gently on the screw heads. It may break apart whatever is sticking.

Answer (score 0):

Find a bolt or screw and knock on those tubes.

To loosen the sticking.

[image: knock]